# Find number of islands and affected area in an image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have the following problem that I wanted to solve using opencv or scikit-image.

Suppose I have a "map" in the following form:
1 is ground 0 is water

```
map = np.array([
  [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
  [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
  [ 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
  [ 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
  [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
  [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

1. How many islands in the map? considering 4 neighbors. In this example there is 2
2. Given an (i,j) position, return the number of ground neighbors.
   example: (2,2) -> 4

Comment: For (1), take a look at [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). (2) is much simpler.

Comment: thanks @nickie! I don't think I understood how to solve 1 using flood fill, could you give me an example?

Comment: You start from (0, 0) and run flood-fill, as long as the cells you encounter are 1. Then you have found the first island, so you increase a counter. You also mark the cells that you have visited (either by using a separate data structure, or by clearing the bits). Then, you continue from the next cell that you haven't visited and start a flood-fill from there, and so on. This will run in O(N*M).

Comment: "floodfill"? no. you need "connected components analysis". don't mess around with "floodfill". what you were just recommended to do with floodfill is a poor man's connected components analysis. use the proper algorithms, they're faster and simpler. https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/scikit-image/auto_examples/plot_labels.html

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html#scipy.ndimage.label

Comment: as for the second question: convolve with a 3x3 "box" kernel, then you can directly read that number for any index

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, there may be a `scipy` function that has this ready. However, if you want to count the "islands", as the original question was, the algorithm to use is an application of flood-filling. You can view it as identifying connected components, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

**Solving question no. 1 with Scikit-Image**: The [`measure`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html) module will be your friend. Please checkout the documentation for it.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.array([ [ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
[ 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
[ 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.],
[ 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
[ 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

imglabeled,island_count = measure.label(img,background=0,return_num=True,connectivity=1)

plt.imshow(imglabeled)
```

[image: labeled image]